# Two divs side by side (one is fixed position)

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to add a fixed division to the left of the webpage that will keep the navbar information and on the right I am trying to add another division. It is currently not allowing me to put them side by side (the one I wanted to add to the right is overlapping with fixed). How can I align them side by side?

Here is my CSS:

```
.left_fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 16%;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #041230;
  z-index: 100;
  min-width: 170px;
}

.right_side {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: post a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. since you set a `width:16%` for the fixed element you should set the rest 84% `width:84%` to the right element.
2. Next set a `max-width` to the right element since the left element has a `min-width` I have set this to `max-width: calc(100% - 170px)`
3. Align the right element to the right by adding `float: right`.

I have made the left element translucent so you can see that there is no overlap.

Read and run the snippet below to understand it in detail.

P.S : I have made the left element translucent so you can see that there is no overlap.

**Hope it helps**

```css
.left_fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 16%;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #0412303f;
  z-index: 100;
  min-width: 170px;
}

.right_side {
  width: 84%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100vh;
  float: right;
  max-width: calc(100% - 170px);
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left_fixed">
  <h1>LEFT SIDE</h1>
</div>

<div class="right_side">
  <h1>RIGHT SIDE</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your styling fails is that the "Position: Relative" will not be relative to the "Position: fixed".

In order to accomplish the effect you are looking for I'd suggest you to use float:left on both elements instead.

Comment: No luck still :( I got it rid of position:relative on right_side and added float: left to both

Comment: @BasakUlcay. What you need to do is to add "Position: relative;" and "Float: left;" to both of them :) The float attribute needs the "position: relative" in order to work properly

Comment: How do I keep the left side fixed if I'm adding relative to that one too? @Zeppo

Comment: I think that the problem is that I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish :) 
By having position relative and float left on 2 objects they will always stay side by side, as long as they both are in the same parent div.

Otherwise, if this is not the solution you are looking for, please describe in other words so that I can understand the situation better :) @BasakUlcay

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the two divs inside a parent div, and then add display flex to the parent div. This will make the two divs next to each other, and then you can add custom width to .left_fixed.

Comment: I tried now but it doesn't show left_fixed as a Flex item and is still overlapping

Comment: You would have to remove the position: fixed on  .left_fixed

Comment: I need it to be fixed though when I scrolled down

Comment: Okay, just add margin-left:16%; to .right_side and add height: 100% to .left_fixed. I would also remove top: 0, left: 0; bottom: 0 from .left_fixed aswell